# SAS: How to set data types and import multiple files and apply these types

Tags: sas

I have multiple excel sheets.Although each field is the same, data types when doing PROC IMPORT results in different data types (character and numeric).

Is there a way to specifically assign data types for each field and then import multiple files and apply these data types ?

Thank you!

Comment: SAS does not normally change the type of cells in a spreadsheet.  The main exception is that empty columns as defined as one byte character fields since that takes less space.  Do you really have Excel files?  If you have TEXT files, like a CSV file, then you can write your own code to read them.

Comment: Find the offending value in your Excel that is causing a numeric column to be interpreted as a character type.  It could be hidden characters such as hard-space ('a0'x), linefeed characters ('0a'x), or some invisible multiple byte UTF character.  Remove said characters and the column will be interpreted as numeric during IMPORT.  In Excel can regex search for non-number representing characters (i.e. things that are not digits or period)

Answer (score 1):

The Proc Import Function doesn't provide a way to specify types.

You have to use a datastep to do so.
There a 2 ways to achive this.

#1 Import via Data step

```
data work.DatasetName;
    infile "&yourPath./&yourFileName..csv"
        lrecl = 200
        termstr = crlf
        encoding = 'wlatin2'
        dlm = ';'
        missover
        firstobs = 2
        dsd 
    ;
    format
        yourNumber   best5.
        yourChar     $char8.
    ;
    input
        yourNumber   : ??   best5.
        yourChar     :      $char8.

    ;
run;
```

For more infos see sas documentation [INFILE Statement](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lestmtsref/n1rill4udj0tfun1fvce3j401plo.htm)

#2 Import via proc import and datatype changes via datastep

See [this post](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/Using-PROC-IMPORT-to-Specify-Variable-Types-and-Formats/td-p/353268)

Comment: Note that works for text files, like the CSV file in your example, but it will not work for actual EXCEL files, like the question asked about.